# How to show API options in Autocomplete and update them

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to update a autocomplete options, but when I try to remove a selected tag (de select) or choose new tag (select) I get this warning in my console log:

> MUI: The value provided to Autocomplete is invalid. None of the
> options match with
> `[{"catName":{"catName":"rfbsdrfbertherth"}},{"catName":{"catName":"sfnojblkigpsm"}},{"catName":{"catName":"jkflnbr.efb"}}]`.
> You can use the `isOptionEqualToValue` prop to customize the equality
> test.

Also this error:

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object
> with keys {catName}). If you meant to render a collection of children,
> use an array instead.

In my **Autocomplete** component **`SelectPostsCatsOptions`** I'm fetching the options from API:

```
export default function SelectPostsCatsOptions({onBlur, selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories, readOnly, value, onChange}) {

    const [postsCats, setPostsCats] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    // FETCH THE CATEGORIES FROM THE DATABASE
    useEffect(() => {
        const getPostsCats = async () => {
          const res = await axios.get("/postscategories");
          setPostsCats(res.data);
          setLoading(false);
        };
        getPostsCats()
      }, []);
    // END OF FETCH THE CATEGORIES FROM THE DATABASE

    return (

        <div>
            <Autocomplete
              readOnly={readOnly}
              multiple
              disablePortal
              id="postsCats"
              getOptionLabel={(postsCats) => `${postsCats.catName}`}
              options={postsCats}
              isLoading={loading}
              loadingText="Loading categories..."
              maxWidth={false}
              disableGutters
              isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.catName === value.catName}
              noOptionsText={"No Available Options"}
              renderOption={(props, postsCats) => (
                <li 
                  {...props} 
                  key={postsCats.id}
                  style={{ …}}>
                  {postsCats.catName}
                </li>
                )}
                value={value}
                // THE TAGS SELECTED
                renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
                  value.map((option, index) => (
                    <Chip
                      key={option.id}
                      label={option.catName}
                      {...getTagProps({ index })}
                      style={{…}}
                    />
                  ))
                }
                // END OF THE TAGS SELECTED
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField
                    readOnly={readOnly}
                    {...params}
                    placeholder="Categories"
                    InputLabelProps={{ …} }}
                    sx={{…}}
                      // THE RIGHT END ICON
                      InputProps={{
                        style: { … },
                        ...params.InputProps,
                        endAdornment: (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                {loading ? <CircularProgress /> : null}
                                {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
                            </React.Fragment>
                        ),
                    }}
                    // END OF THE RIGHT END ICON
                    /> }
                    onChange={onChange}
            />          
        </div>
        
    );
}
```

Then i'm using the Autocomplete here is this page (form).

```
import SelectPostsCatsOptions from "../../components/autocomplete/SelectPostsCatsOptions";

export default function PostInfo() {

    const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
    const [selectedCategories, setSelectedCategories] = useState([]);
    const [postInfoPageUpdateMode, setPostInfoPageUpdateMode] = useState(false);

    // TO FETCH DATA FROM THE DATABASE
    useEffect(() => {
      // TO FETCH POST
      const getPost = async () => {
        try {
          const res = await axios.get("/posts/" + path);
          setPost(res.data);
          setCategories(res.data.categories);
          setIsLoading(false);
          console.log("Post:", res.data);
        // HANDLING ERROR
        } catch (err) {
          setIsLoading(false);
        }
        // END OF HANDLING ERROR
        };
        getPost()
      }, [path]);
    // END OF TO FETCH DATA FROM THE DATABASE

    // HANDLE THE DATA TO SUBMIT
    const handleUpdate = async () => {
      if (!title || !content || !photo ) {
        setAlertMsg({ fail: true, success: false, msg: "All fields are required!" });
        return;  
      } else try {
          await axios.put(`/posts/${post._id}`, {
            username:user.username, 
            categories: selectedCategories.map(cat => cat.catName),
          });
          window.location.reload();
          setPostInfoPageUpdateMode(false);

      // HANDLING ERROR
      } catch (err) {

      }
      // END OF HANDLING ERROR
    };
    // END OF HANDLE THE DATA TO SUBMIT


  return (
    // // POST INFO PAGE
    <div className="PostInfoPage">

      {/* IF THE PAGE IS LOADING SHOW CIRCULAR PROGRESS */}
      {isLoading ? (
            ………
      ) : (
        <>
      {/* POST VIEW OR EDIT CONTAINER */}
      <div className="PostInfoPageBottom" dir="auto">
        {/* POST FORM */}
        <form className="PostInfoPageForm" dir="auto">
                {/* POST CATEGORIES CONTAINER */}
                <div className="PostInfoPagePostContentContainer">
                    <h3>Post Categories:</h3>
                      <SelectPostsCatsOptions
                        selectedCategories={selectedCategories} 
                        setSelectedCategories={setSelectedCategories}
                        readOnly={postInfoPageUpdateMode ? false : true}
                        value={selectedCategories.map((catName) => ({ catName }))}
                        onChange={(event, newSelectedCategories) => setSelectedCategories(newSelectedCategories)}
                      />
                </div>
                {/* END OF POST CATEGORIES CONTAINER */}
        </form>
        {/* END OF POST FORM */}
      </div>
      {/* END OF POST VIEW OR EDIT CONTAINER */}
      </>
      )}
      {/* END OF IF THE PAGE IS LOADING SHOW CIRCULAR PROGRESS */}
    </div>
    // // END OF POST INFO PAGE
  );
}
```

The autocomplete here should show the options chosen from the API (post.categories), which i'm `value` for it, but the issue is when changing (updating) these options, I don't know if it's from `onChange` or something else ! What I'm trying to implement is:

1. show the options (Array) back from API (post.categories)
2. update the options (de-select or select new option)
3. update the option in the API, which i'm using handleUpdate for it

Answer (score 0):

Based on your warning message, probably this is your options passed to Autocomplete component.

```
[
    {
        "catName":{
            "catName":"rfbsdrfbertherth"
        }
    },
    {
        "catName":{
            "catName":"sfnojblkigpsm"
        }
    },
    {
        "catName":{
            "catName":"jkflnbr.efb"
        }
    }
]
```

If so, getOptionLabel is returning a string and isOptionalEqualToValue is returning an object.

```
getOptionLabel={(postsCats) => `${postsCats.catName}`}

Something like this: '{catName:"rfbsdrfbertherth"}'
```

```
isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.catName === value.catName}
Something like this: { catName:"rfbsdrfbertherth" }
```

Ensure to make them return the same type and content.

Comment: how to make them the same ?

Comment: First i would print both with console.log to verify what value they are returning.
If they are the same, convert one of them to same type. For example, you can make the isOptionEqualToValue return a string as well.


`isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.catName === \`${value.catName}\`}`

I am making a guess because, i'm not sure what value they are actually returning. Can you print and confirm that?